# Main Effect plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, experimental-design

I am new to R and ggplot2. I would like to create a main effect plot for a full-factorial experiment I did.

The plot should take the mean of the low level and plot a line to the mean of the high level. As of now I was able to create the means with stat_summary(), but I can't figure out how to connect them while omitting my center point.

Right now I am just using geom_smooth(), which is not ideal.

```r
p <- ggplot(data, aes(t, g_break)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean) + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line")
```

Edit:

I was asked to provide some data.

```r
structure(list(RunOrder = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), us = c(300, 300, 
300, 160, 160, 160), t = c(200, 200, 100, 100, 200, 200), f = c(160, 
400, 400, 400, 400, 160), Blocks = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), g_break = c(0.6, 
1, 0.4, 0, 0.1, 0.6)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you share a part of your data with `dput(head(data))`?

Comment: Sure, I created an edit with my data.

Comment: thanks! But your data does not contain the variables `factor` and `response`  that you use in your `ggplot` code

Comment: Ah, yes. I just wanted to make the example code readable. Now that I added data I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives the same plot as using `geom_smooth`, but I'm not sure whether this is what you mean with "omitting my center point". Since it is the same as you already provided, but just omitting the first `geom_summary`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(t, g_break)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line")
```